# Reducing number of similar methods

Tags: java, algorithm, performance

I have a method which does something from point a to point b (it iterates by incrementation) or from b to a (it iterates by decrementation) through an array.

These two methods have to be a to b and b to a because I do not know at the beginning, where will I end. In my implementation, they vary only in one line.

In more dimensions I still do it only in straight lines. Problem expands from two (left, right) to eight (up, up-right, right, down-right etc.), 32 and so on functions. They also start varying in more lines.

What is the best way to deal with the problem?

I have to deal with it in java.

Example in 2 dimensions (three from eight functions to cover every possibility):

```
void doSomethingToCellsRIGHT(int x, int y) {
    while(condition) {
        board[x][y].changeSomething();
        x++;
    }
}

void doSomethingToCellsLEFT(int x, int y) {
    while(condition) {
        board[x][y].changeSomething();
        x--;
    }
}
void doSomethingToCellsUP_LEFT(int x, int y) {
    while(condition) {
        board[x][y].changeSomething();
        y++;
        x--;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could have just one function with arguments called `dx` and `dy`, and in the loop just do `x += dx` and `y += dy`. Then the usage would be, for example, `doSomethingToCells(x, y, 1, 1)` if you wanted to go up and to the right.

Answer (score 2):

add an enum

```
public enum DIRECTION {
    Right,
    Left,
    Up,
    Down
}
```

You could do this and have multiple optional parameters, where you always need at least one direction;

```
void doSomethingToCells(int x, int y, DIRECTION... directions){
    while(condition){
        board[x][y].changeSomething();

        for(DIRECTION dir:directions){  
            y+= dir == DIRECTION.Up ? 1 : 0;
            y-= dir == DIRECTION.Down ? 1 : 0;
            x+= dir == DIRECTION.Right ? 1 : 0;
            x-= dir == DIRECTION.Left ? 1 : 0;
        }
   }
}
```

and you can call

```
doSomethingWithCells( 1,1, Up, Left) . // This would go x-- and y++
doSomethingWithCells( 1,1, Up)         // This would go y++
```

You could even call

```
doSomethingWithCells( 1,1, Left, Left) .  //This would skip every second cell to the left
```

Comment: It's fine but repetitive (the direction handling would have to be copied in every method) and slow (many conditional jumps). See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44524202/581205).

Comment: Why would the direction handling have to be copied in every method? This method would handle all cases.

Comment: This method handles all directions, when you want to execute `changeSomething`. But you may want to do `changeSomethingElse` with all directions and then you have to copy the direction handling to `doSomethingElseWithCells`. That's why it should be mostly done in the `enum` itself (something like `x += direction.dx; y += direction.dy; ` in the method is the minimum achievable without some `Point`).

Answer (score 1):

Cool, a good question, the codes are quite the same with @Derek but make it more OO:

#### Define the `Move` interface

```
public interface Move {
    public void move(int x, int y);
}
```

#### Implement it in the `enum` with method body

```
public enum Movement implements Move {
    RIGHT() {
        public void move(int x, int y) {
            x++;
        }
    },

    LEFT() {
        public void move(int x, int y) {
            x--;
        }
    },

    UP() {
        public void move(int x, int y) {
            y++;
        }
    },

    DOWN() {
        public void move(int x, int y) {
            y--;
        }
    };
}
```

#### How to use:

```
public void doSomething(int x, int y, Movement... movements) {
    while (condition) {
        board[x][y].changeSomething();

        for (Movement movement : movements) {
            movement.move(x, y);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Call

```
doSomething(1, 2, Movement.DOWN, Movement.RIGHT);
```

Comment: Sorry, this can't work as Java has call by value only (s. [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44524202/581205)).

Comment: @maaartinus Yes, I see, thanks. that's not a really working codes, I just provide a good( maybe ) solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Liping could be an improvement, except for that the method

```
    public void move(int x, int y) {
        x++;
    }
```

does nothing at all (incrementing a local variable is a no-op here).

Anyway, I'd do it in a shorter and probably faster way:

```
public interface Move {
    public int dx();
    public int dy();
}

@RequiredArgsConstructor 
public enum Movement implements Move {
    RIGHT(+1, 0),
    LEFT(-1, 0),
    UP(0, +1),
    DOWN(0, -1);

    private final dx;
    private final dy;
}
```

[The Lombok annotation](https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/RequiredArgsConstructor.html) does exactly what the name says.

The usage should be obvious.